# Wordpress pagination doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I try to add a code to my wordpress blog show previous posts(in a previous page).
I try this code but it don't work:

```
<?php
$paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = array(
    'offset' => 1,
    'cat' => -22,
    'paged'=>$paged
);
$recent = new WP_Query($args);
while($recent->have_posts()) : $recent->the_post();
// here some code to view
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="navigation"><p><?php posts_nav_link('&#8734;','next page','previous page'); ?></p></div>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

it's doesn't work in `http://mydomain.com/page/2`

Answer (score 1):

the reason that the pagination doesn't work was `'offset'` argument

Answer (score 0):

you can use following plugin in your wordpress website:-

1. http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-paginate/
2. http://wordpress.org/plugins/pagenavi-automatic-page-numbers/
3. http://wordpress.org/plugins/alphabetic-pagination/

Comment: When I can use my query, I never use extra plugins.